# How would you code dict getter with maximum sugar code without using any lib?

Tags: python

What would be your solution to add the maximum  code sugar to access get `aze` where name is `default`?

```
def get_live_endpoint_prefix(datacenters) -> str:
# {
#   "dataCenters": [
#     {
#       "name": "default",
#       "prefix": "aze"
#     },
#     {
#       "name": "AU",
#       "prefix": "eza"
#     },
#     {
#       "name": "EU",
#       "prefix": "zer"
#     },
#     {
#       "name": "US",
#       "prefix": "rze"
#     }
#   ],
# }
    for data_center in datacenters.get("dataCenters"):
        if data_center.get("name") == "default":
            return data_center.get("livePrefix")

    return ""
```

Thanks

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Did you mean: `return data_center.get("prefix")` (i.e. prefix rather than livePrefix)?

Comment: checkout python's `filter` function. You can do something like `filter(lambda x: x['key'] == 'value' and something, myArrayofDict)` it will return an array of filtered items and you can select one from it.

Comment: One-liner using generator: `return next((i['prefix'] for i in datacenters['dataCenters'] if i['name']=='default'), '')`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "maximum sugar code" is but here's a possible solution:

```
datacenters = {'dataCenters': [
    {
        "name": "default",
        "prefix": "aze"
    },
    {
        "name": "AU",
        "prefix": "eza"
    },
    {
        "name": "EU",
        "prefix": "zer"
    },
    {
        "name": "US",
        "prefix": "rze"
    }
]
}

def get_live_endpoint_prefix(datacenters):
    try:
        return next(filter(lambda e: e.get('name') == 'default', datacenters['dataCenters']))['prefix']
    except (StopIteration, KeyError):
        pass
    return ''

print(get_live_endpoint_prefix(datacenters))
```

**Output:**

```
aze
```

**Notes:**

Use *get()* in the lambda in case the key *name* is absent.
Use StopIteration exception handler in case no dictionaries exist with a *default* value.
Use KeyError exception handler in case either of the *prefix* or *dataCenters* keys are absent.

Comment: Thanks, I should have said "most convenient syntaxic sugar"